# Surjectivity of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N\otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb R^\mathbb N \to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N\times \mathbb N}$

Tags: tensor-products

Let $C(\mathbb N)=\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ be the set of maps $\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ with its  product real vector space structure.
I am quite sure that the canonical $\mathbb R$-linear map $\phi: C(\mathbb N)\otimes_\mathbb R C(\mathbb N)\to C(\mathbb N\times \mathbb N)$ characterized by $\phi(f\otimes g)(i,j)=f(i)\cdot g(j)$ is not surjective, but I can't give a clean proof nor find a reference.
Could you please help?

Comment: I've put the math back in your title to make it easier to read, but feel free to change it back if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Elliot G. Your title is what my advisor wanted me to write, but I couldn't manage the LATEX. The title is much neater now!